# Joomla ACL permissions after upgrade (1.5=>3.9) broken / how to fix?

Tags: joomla, permissions, acl

I've upgraded a 1.5 Joomla to actual verison 3.9.x and I have now a special permission problem.

Users are categorized by standard groups, coming with Joomla, so there are 2 super users and some "Managers". Super users usually create articles, managers are finalizing und publishing them.

So, in System -> Global Configuration -> Articles -> Permissions is set to "Edit - Allow" and "Edit state - allow", which means that on every new created article managers can edit the articles.

Now, the super user clicks on Content -> Articles -> New and check that (not-yet-saved) permission tab. The "Calculated permission" shows a green "Allowed" state in "Manager" tab - as set in the global configuration.
Now, the article will be saved, and re-opened, now the permission tab in manager shows RED "Forbidden" although its saved with explicit "Allowed".

When changing and saving the corrected state again (on the existing article), the permissions are set correctly and the managers can edit the article.

In the actual state, the super user must create an article, close and re-open it and set the right permissions to make it available to other backend users.

How can I fix that?

My guess:
On the first save, the permissions are not set correctly, so Joomla is using "fallback permissions" which means that just super users can edit that article.

Edit:
Here's an interesting comment in joomla core source code, where permissions are saved:

> @to do: incorrect info When creating a new item (not saving) it uses the calculated permissions from the component (item <-> component <-> global config).
>   But if we have a section too (item <-> section(s) <-> component <-> global config) this is not correct.
>   Also, currently it uses the component permission, but should use the calculated permissions for achild of the component/section.

Comment: You might also try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ok, the main problem was, that the categories were not correctly assigned to the #__assets table, which confused the permissions. I had to open and just re-save permissions on each category and it was fine.
However, thanks for your help!!

Comment: Please respect the design of the Stack Exchange system.  If you managed to self-solve, please post a complete and educational answer - as an answer.  Then you can delete your comment.  Then accept your own answer by awarding it the green tick.  Thank you in advance for taking these actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open and save your superusers. This might at least correct any issue with the actual user, that arised after your wishful upgrade attempt :)

If there are many issues after your upgrade, and your web site is not huge, i would consider doing a fresh install of the latest Joomla, and importing data in a more manual /semi manual way. Else I guess you'll be having issues for a while...